# "attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update" when trying to insert row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm using a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` connected to another `UIViewController` where I intend to be able to add entries from. They are linked through an unwind segue, but whenever I try to actually add an entry, I get this:

> attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in
>   section 0 after the update

This is what I have:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

    switch(segue.identifier ?? "") {

        case "AddItem":

        os_log("Adding a new item.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)

        case "ShowDetail":

            guard let DetailViewController = segue.destination as? ViewController else {

                fatalError("Unexpected destination: \(segue.destination)")
        }

            guard let selectedCell = sender as? TableViewCell else {

                fatalError("Unexpected sender: \(sender)")
        }

            guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: selectedCell) else {

                fatalError("The selected cell is not being displayed by the table")
        }

            let selectedItem = items[indexPath.row]

            DetailViewController.item = selectedItem

    default:

        fatalError("Unexpected Segue Identifier; \(segue.identifier)")
    }
}
```

and

```
@IBAction func unwindToList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? ViewController, let item = sourceViewController.item {

        if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

            items[selectedIndexPath.row] = item

            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .none)

        }

        else {

            items.append(item)

            self.tableView.beginUpdates()

            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: items.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)

            self.tableView.endUpdates()

        }
    }
}
```

and

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return items.count

}
```

and

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "TableViewCell"

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell else {

        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of TableViewCell")

    }

    let item = items[indexPath.row]

    cell.labelName.text = item.name

    return cell

}
```

How can this be fixed?

And forgive me, I am fairly new to Swift. :)

Comment: Either call `reloadData()` **or** `insertRows`, never both. `insertRows` does update the table view.

Comment: I removed reloadData() and it still gives me the same response.

Comment: why are you not using the `-beginUpdates()` and `-endUpdates()` methods on the table-view?

Comment: You need to update your model too. ( like insert you object into the datasource array )

Comment: holex I tried that before, didn't do anything.

Comment: CZ54 I assume you mean to store the data permanently?

Comment: Is it happening on the first insert?

Comment: Yes it is. Haven't tried otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` you need to do it inside a `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` block, after updating your data array. According to [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW9):

> To insert and delete a group of rows and sections in a table view, first prepare the array (or arrays) that are the source of data for the sections and rows. After rows and sections are deleted and inserted, the resulting rows and sections are populated from this data store.

You are doing correctly by changing the array before calling `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` but you need to use **batch updates** instead of `reloadData`.

There is a complete example at the Documentation link that you can check.

Comment: Still the same error. I updated the code if that helps.

Comment: is there any part of the code that you use either `reloadData` or another `insertRows`

Comment: please share your `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` implementation

Comment: I have neither anywhere else. I assume you mean the class implementation which would be `class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {`

Comment: the methods `func tableView(UITableView, cellForRowAt: IndexPath)` and `func tableView(UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int)` would be starting point. But any other from `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` too

Comment: Is that what you need?

Comment: Your first sentence is wrong. You **do not** need *to do it inside a `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` block*. The paragraph in the documentation you are referring to talks about *Batch Insertion, Deletion, and Reloading of Rows and Sections*. ***Batch*** means **multiple** `insert`/`delete`/`move` operations simultaneously. For a **single** operation like in the question `begin/endUpdates` is not needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the TableView's `dataSource` is connected (when using a storyboard or nib) or assigned programmatically. These errors also arise when trying to update a TableView or CollectionView with no `dataSource` assigned.

Comment: How exactly would you connect a dataSource to the view?